# how to get the latitude and logtitude from the result of Location.getCurrentPositionAsync() in react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

this is my code for get device's current location.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Platform, Text, View, StyleSheet, FlatList } from 'react-native';
import { Constants, Location, Permissions, MapView } from 'expo';

export default class Home extends Component {

    state = {
        location: null,
        errorMessage: null,
    };

    componentWillMount() {
        if (Platform.OS === 'android' && !Constants.isDevice) {
            this.setState({
                errorMessage: 'Oops, this will not work on Sketch in an Android emulator. Try it on your device!',
            });
        } else {
            this._getLocationAsync();
        }
    }

    _getLocationAsync = async () => {
        let { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.LOCATION);
        if (status !== 'granted') {
            this.setState({
                errorMessage: 'Permission to access location was denied',
            });
        }

        let location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({ enableHighAccuracy: true });
        this.setState({ location });
    };

    render() {
        let text = 'Waiting..';
        if (this.state.errorMessage) {
            text = this.state.errorMessage;
        } else if (this.state.location) {
            text = JSON.stringify(this.state.location);
        }
        console.log(text)
        return (
            <MapView
                style={{ flex: 1 }}
                region={{
                    latitude: text.coords.latitude,
                    longitude: text.coords.longitude,
                    latitudeDelta: 0.1,
                    longitudeDelta: 0.1,
                }}
            />
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
        backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    },
    paragraph: {
        margin: 24,
        fontSize: 18,
        textAlign: 'center',
    },
});
```

what i wanna do is pass the latitude and logtitude to MapView. but this is not working.

the output of 
`console.log(text)` is

```
{
  "timestamp":1551594077000,
  "mocked":false,
  "coords":{
    "heading":0,
    "longitude":80.4380389,
    "speed":0,
    "altitude":-78,
    "latitude":6.0140343,
    "accuracy":21.238000869750977

  }
```

i'm running this project in my smart phone(galaxy j5 10) using expo application. all location permissions are given to the app and still not working. i tried lots of documentations, but it's not working. how can i correct this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is being caused by your render method:

```
render() {
    let text = 'Waiting..';
    if (this.state.errorMessage) {
        text = this.state.errorMessage;
    } else if (this.state.location) {
        text = JSON.stringify(this.state.location);
    }
    console.log(text)
    return (
        <MapView
            style={{ flex: 1 }}
            region={{
                latitude: text.coords.latitude,
                longitude: text.coords.longitude,
                latitudeDelta: 0.1,
                longitudeDelta: 0.1,
            }}
        />
    );
}
```

When `this.state.errorMessage` is null you don't set a value for the `this.state.location` so your `MapView` tries to use the value you set as `text`, which doesn't work because `this.state.location` is null and will throw an error if you try to access values on it.

When you have got a location you use `JSON.stringify` to convert the location object to a string but that stops you from accessing the properties of the object.

When both `this.state.errorMessage` and `this.state.location` are null your `text` is just a string so it will cause the `MapView` to error because you are trying to access object properties on a string.

You should do something like this:

1. Set an initial value for loaded in state
2. Set loaded state in `_getLocationAsync`
3. Only check location if permission has been granted
4. Refactor render so that it handles the loading of the component (it should show one of 3 different out comes, not loaded, loaded but with an error, loaded but with location)

Here is the refactor

```
export default class Home extends Component {
  state = {
    location: null,
    errorMessage: null,
    loaded: false
  };
  // componentWillMount has been deprecated, use componentDidMount instead
  componentDidMount () {
    if (Platform.OS === 'android' && !Constants.isDevice) {
      this.setState({
        errorMessage: 'Oops, this will not work on Sketch in an Android emulator. Try it on your device!',
        loaded:true
      });
    } else {
      this._getLocationAsync();
    }
  }

  _getLocationAsync = async () => {
    let { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.LOCATION);
    if (status !== 'granted') {
      this.setState({
        errorMessage: 'Permission to access location was denied',
        loaded: true
      });
    } else {
      // only check the location if it has been granted
      // you also may want to wrap this in a try/catch as async functions can throw
      let location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({ enableHighAccuracy: true });
      this.setState({ location, loaded: true, errorMessage: null });
    }
  };

  render () {
    // check to see if we have loaded
    if (this.state.loaded) {
      // if we have an error message show it
      if (this.state.errorMessage) {
        return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text>{JSON.stringify(this.state.errorMessage)}</Text>
          </View>
        );
      } else if (this.state.location) {
        // if we have a location show it
        return (
          <MapView
            style={{ flex: 1 }}
            region={{
              latitude: this.state.location.coords.latitude,
              longitude: this.state.location.coords.longitude,
              latitudeDelta: 0.1,
              longitudeDelta: 0.1
            }}
          />
        );
      }
    } else {
      // if we haven't loaded show a waiting placeholder
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Text>Waiting...</Text>
        </View>
      );
    }
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1'
  },
  paragraph: {
    margin: 24,
    fontSize: 18,
    textAlign: 'center'
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have converted the object into a string with with JSON.stringify(location).

You can't access properties of a string with the . operator.

Instead try leaving it as an object and passing the values to the map component.

Answer (score 1):

You are converting the location to a JSON string. Latlong coordinates are supposed to be floating point values. Try this:

```
state = {
        region: {
            longitude: -122.0840052, //Replace with any initial value here
            latitude: 37.4220181,
            longitudeDelta: 0.04,
            latitudeDelta: 0.09
        }
    };

let { coords } = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});
            this.setState({ region: {
                longitude: coords.longitude,
                latitude: coords.latitude,
                longitudeDelta: 0.04,
                latitudeDelta: 0.09
            } 
        });

<MapView region={this.state.region} />
```

Hope this helps!